# Pipeline to user function parameter problems

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, pipeline, powershell-4.0

For some reason, my program is refusing to work in this scenario:

- I have a custom function that is meant to replace a cmdlet due to lack of flexibility
- I am passing this function a **file or folder** object, through the pipeline

This is the function:

```
function Get-ChildItemCustom {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [System.IO.FileSystemInfo] $item,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [string] $archive_path
    )
    Process {
        Get-ChildItem $item
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use this function just like `Get-ChildItem`: input a `[System.IO.FileSystemInfo]` object, and get all the children (sorted with some extra criteria that I didn't include here) as output.

This is how I call the function:

```
Get-ChildItem $parentfolder_path |
    Get-ChildItemCustom |
    Do-SomethingElse
```

The error returns explains that the results of `Get-ChildItem` (which are verifiably of type `[System.IO.FileSystemInfo]`) are being treated as strings.

> Cannot convert the "E:\Data\VHG-ITC-Test\New folder\archive" value of type "System.String" to type "System.IO.FileSystemInfo".

The type preceding the parameter was not always there. When `$item` did not explicitly have a type, the function would misread the input (supposedly only taking the `Name` property as input):

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\New folder' because it does not exist.

So the function does not seem to be able to accept the object input properly. I want to avoid using strings at all costs, and just move objects around. Have I setup the parameters wrong? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't exactly with your function, but with the way `Get-ChildItem` handles arguments (as [Moerwald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45410579/1630171) already suspected in his answer).

When you call `Get-ChildItem` with a `FileInfo` object as an unnamed argument that argument is passed to the first positional parameter (`-Path`), which expects a string array as input, so the object is cast to a string. However, in some situations casting `FileInfo` objects to a string expands the `FullName` property, while in others it expands just the `Name` property (I can't explain how PowerShell decides when to pick which, though). The latter is what's happening in your case. And since `Get-ChildItem` sees just a name, not a full path, it's looking for the item in the current working directory, which fails.

There are a number of ways to avoid this issue, one of which [Moerwald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45410579/1630171) has already shown. Others are:

- using a pipeline for passing `$item` to `Get-ChildItem`:

  ```
  function Get-ChildItemCustom {
      Param(
          [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
          [IO.FileSystemInfo]$item,

          [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
          [string]$archive_path
      )

      Process {
          $item | Get-ChildItem
      }
  }
  ```
- passing the full path by mapping the property by name:

  ```
  function Get-ChildItemCustom {
      Param(
          [Parameter(
              ValueFromPipeline=$true,
              ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
          )]
          [string[]]$FullName,

          [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
          [string]$archive_path
      )

      Process {
          Get-ChildItem $FullName
      }
  }
  ```

Personally, I'd prefer the last variant (passing by property name).